# Is there a way to define environment-specific mongoose middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to be able to run certain hooks in specific environments only. For instance, I have a `post.save` that does image processing, but I have no need of this hook running during testing. One solution would be to put a check in the hook itself like so:

```
FooSchema.post('save', function processImages() {
  if (process.env.NODE_TESTING) return;
  // do image processing
});
```

But I would prefer not to directly account for state like that in the hook itself. Another, more preferable approach, would be to wrap the hooks and introduce another parameter that accepts a list of environments, so that the hooks would then be defined like:

```
FooSchema.post('save', function processImages() {
  // do image processing
}, { test: false, prod: true });
```

This approach isn't ideal either because I'd prefer not to have to do any wrapping. So, I'd like to hear if this specific need has been addressed by anyone else and, if so, what approach was taken. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the hook install itself:

```
if (!process.env.NODE_TESTING) {
  FooSchema.post('save', function processImages() {
    // do image processing
  });
}
```

This way, it would never be installed in testing.